# antd cards with same height in grid

Tags: antd

How to make cards in a grid with the same height using Ant Design of React version 3.x?

```
const cardInLine = (cards, key) => {
  return (<Row type="flex" gutter={16} key={key}>
    {cards.map(card=>{
      return <Col span={8} key={card.cardName} style={{paddingTop: '8px', paddingBottom: '8px'}}>
        <Card
          size="small"
          actions={[
            <Button className="btn" type="primary" icon="plus" key="keyforreact">
            Add
            </Button>
          ]}>
          <Meta
            title={card.cardName}
            description={card.cardDesc}
          />
        </Card>
      </Col>;
    })}
  </Row>);
}

cards = [{
    cardName: 'item1',
    cardTitle: 'item1',
    cardDesc: 'item1item1 item1item1 item1item1 item1item1 item1item1 item1item1 item1item1item1'
    },
    {
    cardName: 'item2',
    cardTitle: 'item2',
    cardDesc: 'item2'
}]
```

[image]

The expected result is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

Set card height as 100%.

```
<Card
  size="small"
  style= {{height:'100%'}}
  actions={[
    <Button className="btn" type="primary" icon="plus" key="keyforreact">
      Add
    </Button>
  ]}>
  <Meta
    title={card.cardName}
    description={card.cardDesc}
  />
</Card>
```